# Replace existing column with same condition for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The below is my pandas dataframe, each column contains either `0` or `1`. I am trying to replace the existing `'toxic'` with `1` if at least one of the other columns (`severe_toxic`, ..., `identity hate`) contains `1`.

I tried the below code but it gives error.

[image: Dataframe - a1]

Code I tried:

```
# a1 - above dataframe's name
a1['toxic'] = [1 if any(a1[[severe_toxic','obscene','threat','insult','identity_hate']]) ==1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['toxic'] = np.where((df[df.columns[1:]]==1).any(axis=1), 1, df['toxic'])
```

`Input:`

```
   toxic  severe_toxic  obscene  threat  insult  identity_hate
0      0             0        0       0       0              0
1      0             0        0       0       0              0
2      0             0        0       0       0              1
3      0             0        0       0       0              1
4      0             0        0       0       0              0
```

`Output:`

```
   toxic  severe_toxic  obscene  threat  insult  identity_hate
0      0             0        0       0       0              0
1      0             0        0       0       0              0
2      1             0        0       0       0              1
3      1             0        0       0       0              1
4      0             0        0       0       0              0
```

`Setup:`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'toxic':[0]*5,
                        'severe_toxic':[0]*5,
                        'obscene':[0]*5,
                        'threat':[0]*5,
                        'insult':[0]*5,
                        'identity_hate':[0,0,1,1,0]})
```

Comment: If `toxic` already contains 1 and all other columns contain 0, your code returns 1. I'm wondering if this is the OP wants? @prog, can you clarify this point, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `any` from Pandas and not from Python:

```
cols = ['severe_toxic', 'obscene', 'threat', 'insult', 'identity_hate']
a1['toxic'] = a1[cols].any(axis=1).astype(int)
```